# C++ Test if map element exists

Tags: c++

I have an "array" of strings defined as such:

```
typedef map<int, string> strArr;
```

Whenever I do this:

```
strArr args;
if(!args[1]) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

The compiler tells me that there's `no match for 'operator!'` Why is this so, and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
Is there a way of making this work with `bool operator! ()!`

Comment: It's so because you failed to read any documentation, instead choosing to randomly guess!

Answer (score 5):

With `!args[1]`, you're trying to call `operator!` on a `std::string`, and indeed, the error message is right: `std::string` has no `operator!`.

To check whether an element exists in a `std::map`, use [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/). It will return `std::map::end` if the specified key is not in the map:

```
if (args.find(1) == args.end()) { ... }
```

Comment: Then how do I fix it...?

Comment: @LeeYi: What is preventing you from simply reading the documentation?

Comment: I didn't know why that `!args[1]` didn't work. I simply assumed you could do the C++ equivalent of the lua `not args[1]`

Comment: It may be a good time to realize that C++ is not Lua.

Comment: I know that, obviously, but it seems like there are some quirks with C++ that I am unaware of

Comment: @LeeYi Documentation is a great resource, you should use it! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: @LeeYi: Now's a great time to discover that "simply assuming" things _does not work_.